# The separation theorem for infinite dimension?

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is a separation theorem for finite dimensions: Suppose $C$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists $\lambda \in \Lambda_n$ such that $\lambda \cdot x\geqslant 0$ for all $x \in C$ iff for each $x \in C$ there is an $i \in \left\{1, ..., n\right\}$ such that $x_i \geqslant 0$, where $\Lambda_n=\left\{\left(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n\right): \lambda_i \geqslant 0 \text{ for }i=1, ..., n \text{ and } \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_n=1\right\}$. For $n=2$, we can see this theorem does not only imply there exists a separation line, and the slope of this line must be negative.

It seems that Hahn Banach theorem is the infinite dimension counterpart of the regular separation theorem. I was wondering whether there is also an infinite dimension counterpart of this separation theorem. It would be great if the reference is provided. Thank you very much!

Comment: I seem to recall this question asked a few years ago.   But how can we find it?

Comment: In order to relate the Theorem described with the HB Theorem it might be helpful to note that the former is a special case of HB by considering a second convex set, namely $\{x: x_i<0, \forall i\}$, which is required to be disjoint from $C$ in the hypothesis.

Comment: @Ruy Thanks for pointing this out. But the finite dimension theorem here says more than there exists a hyperplane.  The slope of this hyperplane must be negative. Is there an HB theorem containing this additional point?

Comment: I maintain that your entire result follows from HB. If a linear functional is negative on the convex set I described, then it must be represented by a vector $\lambda$ with all $\lambda_i\geq 0$, and you are of course allowed to normalize it so that $\lambda\in\Lambda_n$.